# Can we replace the 'Derivative' terms in sympy coming from the differentiation of sympy.Function variables?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

When the following code is run `Derivative(Ksi(uix, uiy), uix))` and `Derivative(Ksi(uix, uiy), uiy))` terms appear:

```
In [4]: dgN
Out[4]:
Matrix([
[-(x1x - x2x)*(-x1y + x2y)*((x1x - x2x)**2 + (-x1y + x2y)**2)**(-0.5)*Derivative(Ksi(uix, uiy), uix) + (-x1y + x2y)*(-(-x1x + x2x)*Derivative(Ksi(uix, uiy), uix) + 1)*((x1x - x2x)**2 + (-x1y + x2y)**2)**(-0.5)],
[-(-x1x + x2x)*(-x1y + x2y)*((x1x - x2x)**2 + (-x1y + x2y)**2)**(-0.5)*Derivative(Ksi(uix, uiy), uiy) + (x1x - x2x)*(-(-x1y + x2y)*Derivative(Ksi(uix, uiy), uiy) + 1)*((x1x - x2x)**2 + (-x1y + x2y)**2)**(-0.5)]])
```

I would like to replace this `Derivative` terms by, let's say, the symbolic expression of the derivative of a function that I know for example, I would like to set `Derivative(Ksi(uix,uiy), uix) = 2 * uix`.
Is there a neat way to do this substitution and to get a symbolic expression for `dgN` with `Derivative(Ksi(uix,uiy), uix)` set to `2 * uix`? Here is my code:

```
import sympy as sp 

sp.var("kPenN, Xix, Xiy, uix, uiy, Alpha, x1x, x1y, x2x, x2y, x3x, x3y ", real = True) 
Ksi = sp.Function('Ksi')(uix,uiy)
Xi          = sp.Matrix([Xix, Xiy])
ui          = sp.Matrix([uix, uiy])
xix         = Xix + uix
xiy         = Xiy + uiy   
xi          = sp.Matrix([xix, xiy])
x1 = sp.Matrix([x1x, x1y])
x2 = sp.Matrix([x2x, x2y])

N           = sp.Matrix([x2 - x1, sp.zeros(1)]).cross(sp.Matrix([sp.zeros(2,1) , sp.ones(1)]))
N = sp.Matrix(2,1, sp.flatten(N[0:2]))
N = N / (N.dot(N))**(0.5)

xp = x1 + (x2 - x1)*Ksi
# make it scalar (in agreement with 9.231)
gN = (xi - xp).dot(N)
dgN = sp.Matrix([gN.diff(uix), gN.diff(uiy)])
```

Comment: Seems like you'd do it with the same tool you use for any other substitution, the [`subs`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) method. Did that not work?

Comment: I did not make it work. Maybe I did it wrong

Answer (score 5):

The substitution you want can be achieved with

```
dgN_subbed = dgN.subs(sp.Derivative(Ksi, uix), 2*uix)
```

Here Ksi is without arguments (uix,uiy) since those were already declared when Ksi was created.

The syntax would be a little more intuitive if you defined `Ksi` as `Ksi = sp.Function('Ksi')`, leaving the arguments -- whatever they may be -- to be supplied later. Then `sp.Derivative(Ksi(uix, uiy), uix)` would be the way to reference the derivative.

Comment: This is working perfectly. I was adding the arguments after Ksi like `dgN.subs(sp.Derivative(Ksi(uix, uiy), uix), 2*uix)`

Comment: The `Ksi` variable is already called with arguments when you define it. You can either write `Ksi = Function("Ksi")` and call it with arguments every time you us it or `Ksi = Function("Ksi")(uix, uiy)` and use it as just `Ksi` (I would prefer the former case if you ever want to call the function with different arguments).