# Sympy: substitution of derivatives to form a first order ODE system

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am quite newbie to Python and Sympy, so I googled a lot before asking this question.

I am using Sympy to derive equation of motion for a mechanical system by Lagrangian approach, which I managed to do.

```
from math import *
from sympy import *;
from sympy.physics.mechanics import *
from sympy.physics.vector import *

# dynamic symbols, for Lagrange equations
x, z, theta = dynamicsymbols('x  z  theta')
xd, zd, thetad = dynamicsymbols('x  z  theta',1)
xdd, zdd, thetadd = dynamicsymbols('x  z  theta',2)

# Lagrangian potential
L = Symbol('L')
def L(x,z,theta,xd,zd,thetad):
    return 0.5*1*xd**2 + 0.5*100*thetad**2 - 0.5*300*(z)**2+0.5*250*(x+ 100*theta)**2

# build Lagrange equations
LM0 = LagrangesMethod(L(x,z,theta,xd,zd,thetad), [x, z, theta])
equations0 = LM0.form_lagranges_equations()

print(equations0)
```

However I obtain a 2nd order ODE system in 3 variables, which I would like to convert to a 1st order ODE system in 6 variables.

As you can see, output is given in terms of variables x, z, theta and their second derivatives. I cannot manage to get the Lagrange equations in form of variables xd, xdd, etc. so I was thinking to replace derivatives like this:

```
print(equations0[2].subs(Derivative(x,t,t),Derivative(xd,t)))
```

However substitution does not work and I get back the unmodified expression. I have seen [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813269/can-we-replace-the-derivative-terms-in-sympy-coming-from-the-differentiation-o) where such susbstitution seem to work; the difference I see here is the use of dynamicsymbols.

Can anyone suggest how should I treat my equations to describe the system in terms of first order derivatives only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: note: M in function T is undefined.

Comment: This looks like a problem of substitutions for which most of your code is completely irrelevant. On the other hand, as your code isn’t working either, it’s hard to tell. Please [edit] your question to feature a [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the sample code according to your suggestion. It can now easily reproduce the issue.